# How to JSDoc named arguments

Tags: javascript, json, function, jsdoc

In one of my JavaScript files, I had to introduce some optional arguments so I followed [this](https://afontcu.medium.com/cool-javascript-9-named-arguments-functions-that-get-and-return-objects-337b6f8cfa07) guide and arrived at the following method declaration:

```js
function my_func({
    opt1,
    opt2 = 250,
    opt3 = "A message.",
    opt4 = null
}) {
    // Do something
}
```

and I can call it like:

```
my_func({
        opt1: "boom",
        opt4: document.getElementById("some-element"),
        opt3: "A different message.",
        opt2: 200
    });
```

and I can even remove a few arguments and place them in any order.
Now, I want to document it using JSDoc but I was confused that what would my JSDoc comment look like? Because that should define that I have to enter the parameters within curly braces, and I would also have to use a key.

If there is any other way by which I can use named arguments and/or optional arguments, then that would also be appreciated.

Comment: You don't (and JavaScript doesn't) have named arguments, you have a single argument that's an object.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks to let me know that JS does not have named arguments but my implementation is somehow a workaround for that. So can you help in documenting it?

Comment: My point is that what you need to research is how to document an _object_ in JSDoc, which is surely covered by existing documentation, tutorials and Q&A.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try searching for a good resource.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to describe "object" arguments in jsdoc?](//stackoverflow.com/q/6460604/90527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@typedef` for this. Check [this documentation](https://jsdoc.app/tags-typedef.html).

For your case:

```js
/**
 * @typedef {Object} NameMeAsYouLike
 * @property {string} opt1 - opt1 description
 * @property {string} [opt2=250] - opt2 description
 * @property {string} [opt3=A message.] - opt3 description
 * @property {number} [opt4=null] - opt4 description
 */

/**
 * @param {NameMeAsYouLike} name me as you like 
 */
function my_func({
    opt1,
    opt2 = 250,
    opt3 = "A message.",
    opt4 = null
}) {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. Can I enter the description of a property of the new type as well? like `@property {string} opt1 some text as description`.

Comment: You can, I updated the answer with it. Cheers 

Answer (score 6):

Another option is naming your single parameter and specify its sub-params

```js
/**
 * my func has a single object argument
 * @param {Object} params
 * @param {string} params.opt1  - opt1 description
 * @param {number} [params.opt2=250] - opt2 description
 * @param {string} [params.opt3='A message'] - opt3 description
 * @param {Element|null} [params.opt4=null] - opt4 description
 */
function my_func({
  opt1,
  opt2 = 250,
  opt3 = "A message",
  opt4 = null
}) {
  // Do something
}
```

Comment: I like this more, I think anything more than this would already go in the TypeScript direction

Comment: I will leave a link here in case anyone wants to look up this answer in the documentation: https://jsdoc.app/tags-param